# Отсутствует перевод following

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, отслеживание-сообщений

Заметил, что после нажатия "Отслеживать" вместо "Отслеживается" появляется "Following".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] => [image: введите сюда описание изображения]